# How to convert Cuneiform character image (B/W) to colour gradient image (from white to black)?

Tags: image-processing

I have B/W cuneiform character images (obtained through unicode). I want to convert these into a gradient coloured image as shown below. The gradient images were manually created using inkscape. I want to automate this process using an image processing technique, how would I go about it?

**Example 1:**

[B/W cuneiform character image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5aZ9.png)

[Gradient colour output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUKGl.png)

**Example 2:**

[B/W cuneiform character image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCCE4.png)

[Gradient colour output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRAfh.png)

edit:

The white->black gradient emerges from the centroid(?) of the triangles (tetrahedron shapes on real life cuneiform tablets). The gradient images are for displacement maps to imprint the characters on 3d tablets.

Comment: Depends in the software.... in MATLAB you just do `imgradient` and I am sure that python and any other thing that handles images has a similar function.The tool you want will mark the difference on the answers you get, its very important you mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Distance transform" does the job. You can do it with opencv easily with this command:

```
cv::distanceTransform
```